# Measurement Invariance

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, measurement, amos, invariance

My colleagues and I are analyzing data by using multi-group SEM.

**Background**

We would like to know how individuals' commitment in a specific leisure activity influences their well-being. Specifically, we examine the following questions:

1. How do individuals' affective, cognitive, and behavioral commitment influence the level of well-being,and
2. whether the influence of each component (i.e., affect, cognition, behavior) on the level of well-being differ between Chinese vs. American leisure participants.

To address this question, about 500 participants (i.e., Americans and Chinese whose hobby is camping) answered 15 item questions. There are three factors (i.e., affective, cognitive, and behavioral). Each factor has five items. After that, they were asked to answer 3 items related to their well-being.

By using these 15 items of affective-cognitive-behavioral questions, we ran multi-group SEM comparing Americans vs. Chinese.

To best of our knowledge, in order to compare two groups, measurement invariance should be confirmed. We know that the changes of Chi-squre, CFI, and RMSEA have been utilized to assess measurement invariance. However, multi-group SEM provided significant difference between unconstrained and constrained model, which indicates that measurement invariance is not supported.

**Question**

How can we improve constrained model fit to support measurement invariance?

If you give us specific steps to implement model fit improvement strategies, that would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Note: We are using AMOS.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try removing the items which are problematic.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I removed problematic items and it worked well! Thank you very much.

Comment: @JeremyMiles How can one diagnose which indicators are causing problems to the multigroup level of invariance (using R)?